# How to convert month date (mm.yy) in R to month date (mon yyyy)

Tags: r, date

If I have date in this format:

```
date <- c('11.17', '12.17', '01.18')
```

How do I change it to this format:

```
'Nov 2017', 'Dec 2017', 'Jan 2018'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `yearmon` class from `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(date, format = "%m.%y")
#[1] "Nov 2017" "Dec 2017" "Jan 2018"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `?strptime` for details on how to format dates.

```
strftime(strptime(date, "%m.%d"), "%b %d")
# [1] "Nov 17" "Dec 17" "Jan 18"
```

Comment: The 17 & 18 are abbreviated years, not days

Comment: `format(as.Date(paste0(date,".01"), format = "%m.%y.%d"), "%b %Y")` maybe

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` `tstrsplit()`:

```
date_spl <- data.table::tstrsplit(date, "\\.")
paste0(month.abb[as.integer(date[[1]])], " 20", date[[2]])

# "Nov 2017" "Dec 2017" "Jan 2018"
```